# SSL Certificate - untrusted error

Tags: redirect, ssl, https

We procured standard ssl certificate to mydomain.net from godadday.

We shutdown live server mydomain.com, configured new server mydomain.net with ssl, everything works fine.

We have added redirect records in DNS for mydomain.com to mydomain.net

www.mydomain.com redirecting properly to www.mydomain.net

We are experiencing a issue, when any request to https //www.mydomain.com
redirection happening but with untrusted certificate error message.

www.mydomain.com uses an invalid certificate.
The certificate is valid for the following names:
www.mydomain.net , mydomain.net
(Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

Godaddy india support not able to resolve the issue, escalated to US support no update from US support.

Please suggest me how to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
ItsR

Answer (score 1):

Redirection inside a HTTPS connection from domain A to domain B needs a proper certificate for domain A too, which does not seem to be in your case. This is because the redirection happens inside the TLS connection, i.e. the TLS connection needs to be established first which needs the proper certificate.

Comment: Yes, we have certificate for domain A, Now domain A server is down, Is there anything do while generating CSR for domain B, I mean adding alias for domain A.

Comment: How to you redirect from domain A to domain B then if the server for A is down? If you do it by returning the IP address for B when requesting the IP address for A then you must install the certificate for A on server B too.

Comment: I need to install certificate for domain A on server B in ssl.conf?  with separate certificate directive?

Comment: If this is the place where SSL is configured with your server software then yes. Please note also, that if you use the same IP address for multiple domains both server and clients need to support SNI (server name indication). This is supported by most modern browsers and servers, but not supported by IE8/XP, various Android applications and other non-browser applications.

Comment: I tried pointing both certificates in Server B ssl.conf,  multiple RSA server certificates not allowed error message. Please brief me your suggestion.

Comment: All this depends on the server software you use and on details of your setup. If your server should support this and you are not be able to set it up based on the documentation of the server I would suggest that you get help about this at serverfault.com. But don't forget to add the necessary details about your setup, software etc.

Comment: Hi Steffen Thanks, Server OS is Centos and webserver is apache.I will try to post the same in serverfault.com thanks